# How can I access my localhost:8080 with IP?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have nodeJs running on GCP. I've created a simple HelloWorld program using nodejs. The moment I run helloworld, it starts at http://localhost:8080. TO access it, GCP has provided me the internal and the external IP.

Now what I want is, if I simply type xx.xx.xx.xx(external IP)/nodejs, it open http://localhost:8080. Means xx.xx.xx.xx/nodejs it open's my HelloWorld node. I think this can be done via nginx maybe. Well can anybody give me an idea of how is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You should use proxy_pass for requests which their location is /nodejs and send them to localhost:8080. It would be like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    ...
    location /nodejs {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    ...
}
```